# Datatables custom div overlay

Tags: html, css, html-table, datatable, datatables

I want to create custom select div container working together with datatables but there is a problem i faced

This is how it looks **without** datatables (basic html table):

[image]

and this is how it looks **with** datatables:

[image]

As i understand the problem is in datatables overflow but i cant figure out how to deal with this.

Is it possible to make this custom select to be overlayed datatables table as it is with basic html table without datatables?

Here is HTML code of my custom select:

```
<td class='text-center'>
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    class='form-control form-control-sm w-auto'
                    placeholder="Трекинг-система"
                    v-model='LiveEdit_value'
                    @blur='LiveEditBlur'
                    autocomplete="off"
                    v-focus
                >
                <div 
                    class='position-absolute w-auto shadow-sm rounded bg-light'
                    style='max-height: 300px; overflow: auto; z-index: 1'
                >
                    <ul class='list-group'>
                        <a href='javascript:void(0)' 
                            class='list-group-item list-group-item-action py-1 px-2'
                            v-for='trackingsys in filteredTrackingSystems'
                            @mousedown.prevent='LiveEdit_value = trackingsys.name; LiveEditBlur()'
                        >
                            <img :src='trackingsys.logo' width='16' class='mr-1'> {{ trackingsys.name }}
                        </a>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please do not use screenshots of text (code/data/errors). Add the text (formatted appropriately) to the question, instead. See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] - the smallest amount of code and data which we can easily copy/paste from your question, to recreate the problem for ourselves. I cannot recreate your problem using (the screenshot of) the code in your question. You can even provide your MRE as a [runnable example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/12567365).